# Firebase security per user

Tags: javascript, html, security, firebase, firebase-security

I'm working on a site, using firebase
The security was:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

So everyone can add their info, but none can access the main part.
But when someone now types this in the console:

```
ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/users");
ref.createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password
}, function(error, userData) {});
ref.authWithPassword({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }, function(error, authData) {));
ref.remove();
```

all userdata will be removed.
All users have their own uid (e.g. `simplelogin:58`) and storageID (e.g. `-Js18LFoT0SmFi2Iq4GP`)
could I maybe do something with those? I really don't want anyone to be able to remove all of my user data, but I need to let the users edit their own info, and to remove their account when they'd like to.

Here's some of my code:

```
function register() {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }, function(error, userData) {
        if (error) {
            alert("Error creating user: " + error)
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
            var uid = userData.uid


            var usersRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/users/" + uid)
            var newUser = usersRef.set({
                faveShow1: "",
                faveShow2: "",
                faveShow3: "",
                faveShow4: "",
                faveShow5: "",
                faveShow6: "",
                faveShow7: "",
                faveShow8: "",
                faveShow9: "",
                faveShow10: "",
                uid: uid
            });
            //var key = newUser.key();
            //console.log(key)
            login();
        }
    });
}

function login() {
  clear();
    var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.authWithPassword({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            alert("Login Failed!" + error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);

            thisAuthData = authData.uid;
            var usersRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/users/" + thisAuthData);

            usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
console.log(snapshot.val())
                    if (true) {
                        globalAuthData = snapshot.val();
                        //globalKey = amount;
                        var SS = snapshot.val()
                        show1 = SS.faveShow1;
                        show2 = SS.faveShow2;
                        show3 = SS.faveShow3;
                        show4 = SS.faveShow4;
                        show5 = SS.faveShow5;
                        show6 = SS.faveShow6;
                        show7 = SS.faveShow7;
                        show8 = SS.faveShow8;
                        show9 = SS.faveShow9;
                        show10 = SS.faveShow10;
                        //...//




                    }
                }

            }, function(errorObject) {
                alert("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });




        }
    });
}

function removeUser() {
  clear();
    var ref = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/");
    var refSer = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/users/" + thisAuthData)


    ref.removeUser({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }, function(error) {
        if (error === null) {
            alert("User removed successfully");
            refSer.remove();
            logoff();
        } else {
            console.log("Error removing user:", error);
        }
    });
}

function edit() {
  clear();
    var fredNameRef = new Firebase('https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/users/' + thisAuthData);
    var onComplete = function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Synchronization failed');
        } else {
            console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
            console.log(thisAuthData);
            console.log(globalAuthData);
            login();
        }
    };
    if (document.getElementById("form1").value != "") {
        var show1 = document.getElementById("form1").value;
    }
    var show2 = document.getElementById("form2").value;
    var show3 = document.getElementById("form3").value;
    var show4 = document.getElementById("form4").value;
    var show5 = document.getElementById("form5").value;
    var show6 = document.getElementById("form6").value;
    var show7 = document.getElementById("form7").value;
    var show8 = document.getElementById("form8").value;
    var show9 = document.getElementById("form9").value;
    var show10 = document.getElementById("form10").value;


    fredNameRef.update({
        faveShow1: show1,
        faveShow2: show2,
        faveShow3: show3,
        faveShow4: show4,
        faveShow5: show5,
        faveShow6: show6,
        faveShow7: show7,
        faveShow8: show8,
        faveShow9: show9,
        faveShow10: show10,
    }, onComplete);

}

function logoff() {
  clear()
    var ref = new Firebase('https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/')
    ref.unauth();
    //...//
    }
}
```

and my securety rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
         ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      },
     ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't register or update right now...

Answer (score 2):

To make sure a user's information can only be edited by that user, you want to use `auth.uid`.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-security.html

> The most important built-in variable is auth. This variable is
>   populated after your user authenticates. It contains data about them
>   and **auth.uid**, a unique, alphanumeric identifier that works across
>   providers. The auth variable is the foundation of many rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To make it a little more clear, `auth.uid` refers to the currently logged in user, and `$user_id` refers to the location in database. The `$` points to the `$location` rule variable:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/path.html

```
{   "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user"
      }
    }  
  } 
}
```

> When a user authenticates to a Firebase app, three things happen:
>
> - Information about the user is returned in callbacks on the client
>     device. This allows you to customize your app's user experience for
>     that specific user.
> - The user information returned contains a uid (a
>     unique ID), which is guaranteed to be distinct across all providers,
>     and to never change for a specific authenticated user. The uid is a
>     String that contains the name of the provider you're authenticating
>     with, followed by a colon and a unique id returned from the provider.
> - The value of the auth variable in your app's Security and Firebase
>     Rules becomes defined. This variable is null for unauthenticated
>     users, but for authenticated users it is an object containing the
>     user's unique (auth.uid) and potentially other data about the user.
>     This allows you to securely control data access on a per-user basis.

Comment: Okay but if I use push I get yet another type of ID: one in the format of `-Js18LFoT0SmFi2Iq4GP` in which I also store a user's UID and other info about the user. How do I make a rule for that? So the user can only edit the stuff that is along with his UID in that 'folder'???

Comment: Or is there an easier way to store multiple lines of data, which they can edit, in the user their account?

Comment: As long as your application logic is correct, the rule either way it is written above should only allow an authenticated user to view or edit his own information.

Comment: When you use `push()`, you add to a list. The id you're seeing is Firebase's reference to the new list member. You want to use `set()` if the data has a defined path like a username

Comment: Okay I changed my rules, and changed push to set, but now I keep getting permission denied: `FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/simplelogin:73 failed: permission_denied `

Comment: It does make a new account and the email address shows up in the list, but the other data won't store

Comment: For a user to edit data that was added with `push()`, use `key()` to retrieve the id generated by Firebase.

Comment: Yes I did that. `  var usersRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/users")
                var newUser = usersRef.push({
                    faveShow1: "",
                    faveShow2: "",
                    faveShow3: "",
                    faveShow4: "",
                    faveShow5: "",
                    faveShow6: "",
                    faveShow7: "",
                    faveShow8: "",
                    faveShow9: "",
                    faveShow10: "",
                    uid: uid
                });
                var key = newUser.key();`

Comment: Are you using the Simulator in the Dashboard? That can give you more detailed information about `permission_denied`

Comment: Okay I edited my code to abandon the random string made by push(), so that should be easier .

Comment: I think using set in stead of push has solved a lot :)

Comment: But I can't create a new user, or remove my own account

Comment: Or edit my info, at all. I could, once, but not after that

Comment: At a meeting I'll take a look after

Comment: Ah I looked more closely at your code above. I think there's an issue in the structure of the code you're using to save data.

Comment: so if your data structure looks like this `"users": {
 "Jon Snow": {
  "faveShows": {
   faveShow1: "",
   faveShow2: "",
   ...
  }
 }
}`

Comment: you want to save like this `usersRef.set({
  "Jon Snow": {
    faveShows: {
     faveShow1: "Breaking Bad",
     faveShow2: "The Walking Dead",
     faveShow3: "Game of Thrones"
    }
  }
});`

Comment: Okay I changed the structure, but it keeps saying `[Warning] FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/simplelogin:82 failed: permission_denied  (firebase.js, line 39)`

Comment: I think it's because there is no main write true rule for users?